# Query function not working with spaces and parenthesis in column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with spaces and parenthesis in column names.I am trying to use `query` method to get the results. It is working fine with `target_names` column but getting error for `sepal length (cm)`.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])
y = pd.DataFrame(iris['target'], columns=['target_names'])
data1 = pd.concat([x,y], axis=1)
data1.query('`sepal length (cm)` > 5')
```

For this I am getting this error:

```
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    petal_length_(_cm_)_BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING >5
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in the `pandas` library. It accepts spaces but not special characters like `$`, `(` etc.

One possible solution is to rename the columns and then use the query function call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have reason to use the `query` function?

just try this :

```py
data1[data1['sepal length (cm)'] > 5]
```

Or change columns name, just like @abhilb said.